# Does the equation $a^2+d^2+4=b^2+c^2$ have any solutions?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Does the equation have $a^2+d^2+4=b^2+c^2$ where $d<c<b<a$ have any integer solutions? This isn't a homework problem, but I need to know for a separate problem I'm doing. Wolfram Alpha isn't very helpful.

Comment: For finding the positive solutions maybe you can try write it as. $c^2-d^2 = 4 + a^2 - b^2 $.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494534/relationships-between-the-elements-a-b-c-d-of-a-solution-to-a2b24-c2d/727499#727499

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$6^2+1^2+4=5^2+4^2$.  Note the difference between the even squares $\bmod 8$.

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below has parameterization:

$a^2+d^2+4=b^2+c^2$

$(2m)^2+(m-2)^2+(2)^2=(m+2)^2+(2m-2)^2$

For, $m=5$, we get:

$(10,3,2)^2=(7,8)^2$

Hence, the integer $4$ can be represented by sum difference of four squares.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below has solutions:

$a^2+d^2+4=b^2+c^2$

$a=8w(k-2)$

$b=w(k^2-2k+5)$

$c=2w(k^2-6k+13)$

$d=w(k^2-10k+21)$

Where, $w=[1/(k^2-4k-1)]$

For $(k,w)=(4,-1)$  we get,  $(a,b,c,d)=(16,13,10,3)$

For $(k,w)=(0,-1)$  we get,  $(a,b,c,d)=(21,5,26,16)$

Where, $k$ is a parameter's

Comment: Good to see a parametric family, but the OP wants to enforce the ordering $d<c<b<a$.  Place suitable restrictions on $k$ maybe?  How does this formula derive the solution $(6,5,4,1)$?